# Why creating an instance can be sometimes slower than calling a function that creates an instance ?

Tags: javascript, class, firefox, browser, chromium

given this class

```
class TestClass { constructor(a) { this.a = a } }
```

... and this wrapper function

```
 function createTestClass(a){  return new TestClass(a)  }
```

... and the defined variable X and variable R

Measurement shows that, in firefox (and, to a lesser extent, in chromium)

```
R = createTestClass(X)
```

is faster than

```
R = new TestClass(X)
```

Here is the jsperf test [comparison](https://jsperf.com/new-vs-function-new)

The wrapper being faster that the wrapped part puzzles me. Is there a flaw in the measure, or an optimization occurring only in function ?

Comment: When I clicked Run (Firefox), `direct` ended up 0.35% faster. Second time 1.49% faster.

Comment: In Safari the "direct" call is nearly 4 times faster, but both are hundreds of millions of ops/sec (126 M vs 464 M), so what's the point? In Firefox the function version is 15% slower.

Comment: @RobG I changed question title to reflect your comment